# How to show tooltip on disabled control in ASP.NET WebForms?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

```
                    chkRecEditJob.Visible = false;
                    btnSubmit.Enabled = false;
                    string tootltip = "You are not authenticate for this.";
                    btnSubmit.ToolTip = tootltip;
```

For certain condition I have to show Tooltip on my Disabled button, but I am unable to do it.

Can Anyone guide me on this?

Comment: If .net tooltip can't help you, you can use Others as: https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Comment: Will jquery works on Disabled button ??

Comment: jquery ui is totally separated from asp.net. It works on html generated from asp.net